# General issue with Java inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

Assumed, we have given the two classes:

```
package inheritance1;

public class Foo1 {

    protected void sayWhoYouAre() {
        System.out.println("I am Foo1");
    }
}
```

and

```
package inheritance2;

import inheritance1.Foo1;

public class Foo2 extends Foo1 {

    public Foo2() {
        // why does this not work?
        // new Foo1().sayWhoYouAre();
        // ---> Error: "The method sayWhoYouAre() from the type Foo1 is not
        // visible"
    }

    @Override
    protected void sayWhoYouAre() {
        System.out.println("I am Foo2");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // why does this not work?
        // new Foo1().sayWhoYouAre();
        // ---> Error: "The method sayWhoYouAre() from the type Foo1 is not
        // visible"
    }
}
```

Why is the `sayWhoYourAre()`-method visible in the class definition so I can override it (`@Override`), but when I try to invoke it by `new Foo1().sayWhoYouAre()` the compiler says, that this method is not visible?

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: protected means the method is only visible for classes the same package or subclasses of those.
In which context do you call `new Foo1().sayWhoYouAre() `?

Comment: Isn't the constructor part of the subclass and so the protected method should be visible?! That I can't invoke it out of the main method, I've understood now!

Comment: Yes you can invoke it from its constructor, but your not doing that here.

Answer (score 0):

`protected` means that the method is visible in:

- the same package of the class on which it is defined
- any class that extends the class in which is defined.
  This covers the case why you can override it in `Foo2`

The main method however is static and therefore not part of the object scope of the class, meaning that it lies not within the inheritance hierarchy. For that reason `sayWhoYouAre` on `Foo1` is not visible.

See also the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2)